# Django HTML quality and tutorials

Tags: html, django, python-3.x

Hey I recently heard about Django, and will hopefully be moving on to learn an HTML type platform. I am currently learning python 3 and wanted to know if Django, especially recent editions, are the "best" ( sorry about the arbitrariness of that). 
Plus I was hoping to know any good books / tutorials for django or any other that you believe is more vesitile, easy, etc. Most books don't seem to be up to date on Django as there have apparently been big changes from 1.0 to 1.1 and another leap on 1.3, from what I've read.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: A number of points to consider: 1) Django does not currently run under Python 3, 2) The docs on the Django site are excellent and definitive, 3) Django is *not*, IMHO, a beginner's platform, especially if you are just learning HTML. There are no theme collections like there are for WordPress. Many shared-hosting companies do not support Python, or support it poorly; WebFaction.com is a notable exception.

Answer (score 1):

As Peter said, Django doesn't support python 3 (which isn't really a big deal and you shouldn't worry about it)

Check out the starter [Django Tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial01/) - see if you understand what's going on (Do all of it!)

If you want to just "make a website" I would recommend learning to build raw HTML/CSS websites before jumping into django which is a web framework.

Python is a joy to learn - it sounds like you are jumping into that world. I would work with the basic tutorial - Read through Model View Controller architecture - and see if it clicks with you.

Answer (score 0):

I can share my experience with you as I have recently learned Django.
Instead of following any book you should try to use the Django documentation and also dont be afraid to look at the source code, it will help you to understand how things are working behind the scene.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, but from the other post by @hackinglife, he/she is suggesting that it would be too advanced for me. I am only starting out on python as my first language and have gotten through http://thinkcspy.appspot.com/build/index.html pretty quickly and thoroughly. I have what should be a good book for GUI programming with PyQt, and I was planning on getting some HTML platform after I get through that. So for the sake of multiple opinions, should I start off on an easier HTML setting/ learn more theory of how it all operates, or will Django pretty much help me with all of that?

Comment: in that case getting familiar HTML at first will be the better option..then come to Django. also I want to add that while u are studying python, make sure u get through the concepts of class, meta class & decorators. they will be used more often when u will start Django.